# Can stability of computation of best least squares polynomial 1d approximation depend on x scale/shift?

Tags: least-squares, floating-point, numerical-calculus

I am using a least square polynomial approximation to find smooth curves approximating data coming from image analysis. More specifically I've blobs of pixels that I know are a reasonably smooth almost horizontal slightly fat line in an image and I want to find the best mathematical curve $y=p(x)$ where $p$ is a polynomial that minimizes the total "error" defined as

$$
E = \sum_i\left(y_i - p(x_i)\right)^2
$$

The solution is found by setting to zero the partial derivatives $\partial E \over a_i$ for all coefficients $a_i$ of the polynomial. This produces a linear system of $n+1$ equations in $n+1$ unknowns for a degree $n$ polynomial that is then solved explicitly with a Gauss-Jordan solver.

The code works and I get reasonable results when using low-degree polynomials (up to 5). What I find strange is that the numerical stability increases a lot (no problems even with degree 15) if I do a very simple shifting and scaling transformation:

$$
x' = 2{x - \bar{x} \over x_{\rm max} - x_{\rm min}}
$$

Transforming also $y$ doesn't seem to have any effect (and thinking to how $y$ values are used that's not a big surprise).

Does this happen because my solver is bad (I'm using a Gauss-Jordan solver with pivoting I wrote myself so that's not to exclude) or it's a intrinsic problem of floating point math?

The image is about 4000 pixels wide so un-scaled data computation has to deal with numbers rather large (e.g. $4000^{30} \approx 10^{108}$ for a degree 15 polynomial) but I thought that FP was designed exactly to handle this case and a double-precision value can handle up to $10^{300}$ (I also found no mention of this scaling/shifting issue and problems begin to appear even at just degree 7).

Sorry if this is a trivial question but I know very little about numerical analysis.

Comment: Are you solving the normal equations directly? If so, perhaps consider using QR instead.

Comment: @copper.hat: I've added a description of what I do (explicitly solving the system you get by setting to 0 partial derivatives). So you are saying that the problem is in the solver, not that the matrix is inherently (numerically speaking) worse for unscaled values, correct?

Comment: Solving the normal equations (which I believe is what you are doing) can result in a system that has a condition number that is the square of the condition number of the system used to solve the system with say QR/Gram Schmidt. The condition number is a measure of how noise gets amplified, so bigger is worse.

Comment: @copper.hat: The question is why a simple shift/scaling helps? Or it really doesn't and what I am observing is just because my solver is buggy?

Comment: I would guess (just a guess) is that shifting scales the problem well and results in a smaller condition number.

Comment: @copper.hat: I tried using `numpy.linalg.solve` and while much better than my Gauss-Jordan solver working on the original data, is still much worse than using my solver over scaled/shifted data. That solver uses in my case LU decomposition (dgesv from LAPACK).

Comment: You need to use something that is specific to least squares to avoid the squared conditioning. It is not just a better solver, it is a solver specific to the least squares problem.